# Drag strokes on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am writing a code block to move ink stroke and I am able to move the stroke, but the length of stroke is increasing while moving and the shape of the stroke is changing. I am not able to find the reason for this issue.

I am tracking x,y on mouse down and mouse move and moving the strokes on mouse move by clearing the canvas and redrawing it on mouse move.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AA123456/phcc4zv8/)**

**Code block for mouse move:**

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
  if (dragging){
    selection.moveX =  mousePos.x; 
    selection.moveY =  mousePos.y; 
    var l= selection.arrlineX.length;
    for (var i = l-1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
      selection.arrlineX[i]=(mousePos.x-dragoffx)+     selection.arrlineX[i];
      selection.arrlineY[i]=(mousePos.y-dragoffy) +  selection.arrlineY[i];
    }
    valid = false; // Something's dragging so we must redraw
    draw();
  }
}, true);
```

Any pointers will be really appreciated.

Comment: What is the intention when the mouse is clicked and moved? Should the red stroke just move or do you want something to be drawn?

Comment: I resolved this. here the issue is that dragoff variables are not getting updated.